# dlang How to import a Magick++ class from C++ into D

Tags: imagemagick, d, dllimport

How can I import a class from a library in D?
Is there something I am doing wrong? I had imported functions from dlls through libs successfully but never a class.

trying to import a class from .lib getting these errors:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Magick::Image::write(char const *)" (?write@Image@Magick@@QEAAXPEBD@Z) referenced in function _Dmain
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Here is the way I try to import the class, I think these are the correct definitions but might be wrong:

```
pragma(lib, "library.lib");
extern (C++){
    Image createImage(const(char)*);
    void deleteImage(ref Image d);
}

pragma(lib, "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/lib/CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib");
pragma(lib, "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/lib/CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib");
pragma(lib, "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/lib/CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib");
extern (C++,Magick){
    void InitializeMagick(const(char)*);
    //void InitializeMagick(const(char)* __ptr64);
    class Image{
        //There are errors trying to import any constructor or function
        //this();
        //this(const(char)*);
        final void write(const(char)*);
    }
}

int main(string[] args){
    Magick.InitializeMagick("");
    Magick.Image img = createImage("screenshot:");
    img.write("file.jpg"); //linking problems after adding this line
    return 0;
}
```

This is the function I am trying to import in D:

```
void Image::write(const string &filename);
```

Comment: take those constructors out, you can't construct a C++ class in D. You'll have to make a C++ helper function to create and destroy it.

Comment: ok I think I get it but in the website there is this example: https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html I thought they defined the class to use it but I can see now they create an instance so what's the point to add the class there.

Comment: Which class and which example? The first one under "Using C++ Classes From D" has createInstance and destroyInstance to handle the construction/destruction, and "using D Classes From C++" is different because there, the class is actually written in D and C++ just looks at it (so in that case, the new/delete must be done in D, not C++). But when using C++ classes from D, you define the class so you can call its members, not so you can create it.

Comment: A problem is when the class and methods are declared, I am getting these errors so I really can't use them. I think this might be a case of mismatching types.

Comment: as @adam-d-ruppe said remove the constructors and make your own wrappers. And I noticed on the ImageMagic version on my computer that the `write` method is not marked as `virtual`, so you need to mark it as `final` because methods in D are virtual by default in contrast to Cpp.

Comment: @سليمانالسهميSoulaimaneSahmi thank you I did so (added the wrappers) and the program is compiling but a `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` is still present for write `final void write(const(char)*);` when I try to call the function

Comment: that is because the function takes `const std::string` not `const char*`, although a cpp compiler would do the convertion automatically but the name mangling is different, looks like you need to port the headers for std::string, I looked into that and it does not look feasible it's too ugly. I'd recommend using [htod](http://dlang.org/htod.html) to automate the header porting. Just run it against your `Image.h`.

Comment: If allocate the std::string on the cpp side and pass it by pointer/reference you can get away with it with much less boilerplate, I'll post a concrete answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the constructor and `write` method for the class `Image`   take an std::string not a `char*`. You are not getting complaints from `createImage` because it converts `char*` to `std::string` on the cpp side, but you are getting complaints from `Image.write` because the D compiler cannot conevert `char*` to `std::string`.
You need to teach the d compiler about `std::string` and make wrappers around `std::string` the same way you did for `Magick::Image`.
If you create the `std::string` on the cpp side on the heap and only pass a pointer you can get away with it without much boilerplate. here is an example:

```
// wrapper.cpp
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <string>

Magick::Image* createImage(const std::string &imageSpec_)
{
    return new Magick::Image(imageSpec_);
}

void deleteImage(Magick::Image *&image)
{
    delete image;
    image = NULL;
}

std::string* createCppString(const char *s)
{
    return new std::string(s);
}

void deleteCppString(std::string *&sp)
{
    delete sp;
    sp = NULL;
}
```

```
// imm.d
pragma(lib, "wrapper.lib");
extern (C++, std)
{
    // std::string boilerplate
    struct allocator(T);
    struct char_traits(CharT);
    struct basic_string(CharT, Traits=char_traits!CharT, Allocator=allocator!CharT);
    alias string = basic_string!char;
}

pragma(lib, "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/lib/CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib");
pragma(lib, "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/lib/CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib");
pragma(lib, "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/lib/CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib");extern (C++, Magick)
{
    void InitializeMagick(const(char)*);
    class Image
    {
        @disable this();
        final void write(ref const(std.string));
    }
}

extern (C++)
{
    Magick.Image createImage(ref const(std.string));
    void deleteImage(ref Magick.Image);
    std.string* createCppString(const(char)*);
    void deleteCppString(ref std.string*);
}

void main() {
    Magick.InitializeMagick("");

    auto imgsrc = "screenshot:".createCppString;
    scope(exit) deleteCppString(imgsrc);

    Magick.Image img = createImage(*imgsrc);
    scope(exit) deleteImage(img);

    auto filename = "file.jpg".createCppString;
    scope(exit) deleteCppString(filename);

    img.write(*filename);
}
```

---

But if you want to create the `std::string` (on the cpp side) on the stack and pass it around by vale instead of passing around a pointer you need more boiler plate, you need to fill in the fields of `base_string`

```
struct basic_string(CharT, Traits=char_traits!CharT, Allocator=allocator!CharT);
{
    // fill in the fields ...
}
```

this the optimal way to do it, but good luck with that (`base_string.h` is not very friendly), but you can let a tool do the hard work for you such as [htod](http://dlang.org/htod.html).

Comment: you're right, it's a very complex thing to try to define std::string, I actually derived the Magick::Image class so I could wrap the write function with a const char* parameter, that made things a lot easier. thank you very much for clearing this up